# Call Java program from PHP

Tags: java, php, exec

I created a Java program which sends an email from my gmail account.  I programmed it in Eclipse and it works fine.  But when I attempt to call it from PHP i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
  at sendVerificationEmail.main(sendVerificationEmail.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Here's the command Eclipse uses:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:53094 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/****/dir/to/program/java/bin:/home/****/dir/to/program/java/lib/javamail-1.4.4/mail.jar sendEmail
```

Here's the command PHP uses:

```
exec("java -classpath /home/****/dir/to/program/java/bin:/home/****/dir/to/program/java/lib/javamail-1.4.4/mail.jar sendVerificationEmail $name $email $comments");
```

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP to send it instead?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Yes, I agree with minitech. I'm not sure why you can't send mail using php. But here is a link that will show you how to do execute an external program in java -> http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/

Comment: Perhaps we can assume that the Java program is sufficiently complex that it's worth not rewriting in PHP. And even if it's not, the fact that it's _possible_ to mail in PHP is by the by - this error might happen for a more reasonable usage of Java.

Comment: @Paul Do you get the same error if you run it from the command line (not in PHP)?

Comment: I don't use PHP because it can come up as spam.  The Java program I use actually connects and logs into gmail then sends the mail.  @aaaidan, no, the PHP command works in terminal.

Comment: "I don't use PHP because it can come up as spam" eh? So now email clients differentiate spams by what programming language it was sent from?

Comment: Yeah I gotta say, PHP _is_ capable of logging into an SMTP server and sending mail from it.

Comment: Even so, that's very odd that the command works in Terminal, but not from PHP. Makes me wonder if PHP is running the command with different environment variables, or in a different working directory. Assuming *nix, do an "env" command in the terminal and in PHP, and see what the differences are, if any...

Comment: Also, I assume that it's a typo that the Eclipse command uses "sendEmail" where the PHP command uses "sendVerificationEmail" ?

Comment: @NiftyDude, reread the comments above and think about how both programs will execute.  Mail can be generated/sent from anyone who's running a server.  The PHP mail function doesn't authenticate the user, therefore I could send mail as anyone, aka spam.

The Java program, as I explained above, logs into Google's server then sends the mail.  I believe spam filters are a less willing to filter out a gmail message than a message from some "random" server.

Comment: @Paul Glad to see you found a direct and useful answer. I don't want to drag this out, but as an aside I just want to make it clear that PHP is perfectly capable of authenticating into an SMTP server ("Google's server") to send mail. Check out http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-smtp.net-smtp.auth.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jar file containing the javax.mail... classes to your command:

For example the following will add the current directory (.) and javax.jar to the classpath:

```
(linux)   java -classpath .:javax.jar com.me.MyMailClient
(windows) java -classpath .;javax.jar com.me.MyMailClient
```

javax.jar is not what it will be called, that's just to show you where you'd put it.  To find out where Eclipse is getting the javax.mail.* items, look at your Project->Properties->Build Path->Libraries tab.  One of the jars listed there is what you need (you can see the contents of jars by unzipping).  It might be called mail.jar, j2ee.jar, javamail.jar - there are a few different likely candidates.  Since your test app is simple it should have few dependencies so you'll be able to spot it easily.

You will need to put a copy of this jar file near run script (the above example assumes it is in the same directory as you are running the java command).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your webserver (for ex APACHE) is not able to locate the java class files in the class path
what you have to do is either change your class path using CLASSPATH environment variable to a location where the Jar/classes is there, or put you classes/jar file to the lib directory of the APACHE (APACHE/lib) and restart the server .

hope it helps